# Java преобразование Object в String[]

Tags: android, объекты, java

Мне требуется прочитать `String[] arr` из `TreeMap<Integer,String[]> treeMap`. Также существует `String[] mapKeys` с ключами `treeMap`. Я использую следующий код:

```
Log.d(TAG, "1");
arr = (String[])treeMap.get(mapKeys[0]);
Log.d(TAG, "2");
```

Логи:

```
1
```

Ошибка:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
```

После этого приложение слетает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeMap<Integer, String[]>` означает, что ключ типа `Integer`, а `mapKeys[0]` имеет очевидно тип `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Почему ключ имеет тип `Integer`, а вы пытаетесь читать с ключем типа `String`? Может быть нужно сначала преобразовать значение из массива строк к числу?

Что значит приложение слетает? Стектрейс есть или мы должны гадать?